# Java thread work unexpected

Tags: java, multithreading

I am  reading [this topic](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/) about java Thread.

And there is an example:

```
import java.util.Vector;

class Producer extends Thread {

    static final int MAXQUEUE = 5;
    private Vector messages = new Vector();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                putMessage();
                //sleep(5000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    private synchronized void putMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        while (messages.size() == MAXQUEUE) {
            wait();
        }
        messages.addElement(new java.util.Date().toString());
        System.out.println("put message");
        notify();
        //Later, when the necessary event happens, the thread that is running it calls notify() from a block synchronized on the same object.
    }

    // Called by Consumer
    public synchronized String getMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        notify();
        while (messages.size() == 0) {
            wait();//By executing wait() from a synchronized block, a thread gives up its hold on the lock and goes to sleep.
        }
        String message = (String) messages.firstElement();
        messages.removeElement(message);
        return message;
    }
}

class Consumer extends Thread {

    Producer producer;

    Consumer(Producer p) {
        producer = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String message = producer.getMessage();
                System.out.println("Got message: " + message);
                //sleep(200);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Producer producer = new Producer();
        producer.start();
        new Consumer(producer).start();
    }
}
```

And the author said:

```
A possible output sequence:
Got message: Fri Dec 02 21:37:21 EST 2011
put message
put message
put message
put message
put message
Got message: Fri Dec 02 21:37:21 EST 2011
Got message: Fri Dec 02 21:37:21 EST 2011
Got message: Fri Dec 02 21:37:21 EST 2011
Got message: Fri Dec 02 21:37:21 EST 2011
Got message: Fri Dec 02 21:37:21 EST 2011
put message
put message
put message
put message
put message
Got message: Fri Dec 02 21:37:21 EST 2011
Got message: Fri Dec 02 21:37:21 EST 2011
Got message: Fri Dec 02 21:37:21 EST 2011
```

But when I run this code I got this result:

```
put message
put message
put message
put message
put message
put message
Got message: Tue Sep 24 16:44:59 CST 2013
Got message: Tue Sep 24 16:45:00 CST 2013
put message
Got message: Tue Sep 24 16:45:00 CST 2013
put message
Got message: Tue Sep 24 16:45:00 CST 2013
put message
..............
```

What is the problem?

Any one can explain it for me?

Comment: What problem are you referring to? The outputs look similar...

Comment: Since it looks like the output of the author comply with some kind of rule. For example five `put message` and then five `got message`, and where the `five` is equal to the `MAXQUEUE`, then I though if I miss anything. I really do not know if this deserve some down votes.

Comment: It doesn't deserve the downvotes, I agree with that. +1

Answer (score 4):

The author's entire point is that the order of tasks between different threads is unpredictable. He printed **a possible output sequence**, but many, many others are possible.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already explained output I must add that the book you are reading doesn't seem to be a very good source to learn from. It teaches to:

1. extend `Thread`, a notorious bad practice;
2. invoke `wait` and `notify` on a `Thread` instance—another known, [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29) bad practice.
3. use the `wait` and `notify` mechanism in the first place, which has mostly been superseded by much more convenient and simpler `java.util.concurrent` tools such as `CountDownLatch`, `Semaphore`, and `Phaser`.

Comment: Oh, I did not notice them. BTW, can you recommend me some sources?

Comment: I don't have a big favorite, but Oracle's online tutorials should be quite good.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of output is correct. Because "Got Message" is not possible without "put message". I mean, if there is no message in queue then how can you retrieve the message. Developer in his example might have given sample output which was not actual code run output but self made just for example.

Remember :
[Count of total "Got message" till particular line] will always be <= [Count of total "put message" till that very line]

Answer (score 0):

The only strange thing is that there are 6 consecutive "put message" which seems to be impossible because the maximum queue size is 5.

But this is because the code sequence

```
producer.getMessage()
System.out.println("Got message: " + message);
```

is - of course - not atomic and has been interrupted by a thread switch.

By the way - always use `notifyAll()` instead of `notify`.